# Find all points of finite order on the elliptic curve $y^2+7xy=x^3+16x$.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am studying Rational Points on Elliptic Curves by Silverman and Tate. This is Problem 2.12 (h).

> Determine all of the points of finite order on the elliptic curve $y^2+7xy=x^3+16x$. Also determine the structure of the group formed by these points.

I have done the other ones that are in Weierstrass standard form with integer coefficients, for example $y^2=x^3-43x+166$. The methods are:

1. Use the strong Nagell-Lutz theorem. Find $y$ such that $y^2|D$. Try those $y$ values and find the corresponding $x$ values. If they are integers and satisfy the equation of the curve, check if they have finite orders.
2. Use the Reduction Modulo $p$ theorem. Find a prime $p$ such that $p\nmid 2D$. Reduce the equation to modulo $p$. The finite order points on the original curve is a subgroup of the finite order points on the new curve.

These methods work well for the curves with standard form. But for $y^2+7xy=x^3+16x$, I am not sure what to do. I can make change of variable, of course, to transform it into $Y^2=x^3+\frac{49}{4}x^2+16x$. But this introduce a fraction coefficient, also the change of variable involves a fraction $Y=y+\frac{7}{2}x$. With this the reduction modulo $p$ would not work. Even the N-L theorem is about integer division.

**My question:**

How can I get rid of the fractions? Or is there another way to find the finite order points?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Has good reduction at $5$, $7$, and (I think) at $11$, with $8$, $8$, and $16$ points, respectively, but the $2$ division over $\Bbb Q$ is cyclic. I’m willing to wager that it has eight rational torsion points, cyclic.

Comment: @Lubin: It did turned out to be order $8$, cyclic, with some laborious computations. I also got the $8,8,16$ with primes, but haven't learned about $2$ division yet. So had to use N-L theorem eventually.

Comment: Oh, 2-division is easiest: that's where the tangent is vertical.

Comment: @Lubin: I see. I know that then. Just terminology.

Comment: And 3-division points are the points of inflection.

Answer (score 1):

Your curve $y^2 + 7xy = x^3 + 16x$ is isomorphic to $y^2 = x^3 - 44091x + 3304854$. Maybe you can find the transformation between these two models yourself?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll try and get back to you.

Comment: I got $y^2=x^3+196x^2+4096x$. I'm not sure how you got your numbers though, and whether they are also isomorphic. I realized that the fractions in the transformation do not matter. Thanks!